# Can I use Apache Tomcat 7 with servlet api 2.5

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, seam

There is a leak with tomcat 6, so I am upgrading to tomcat 7.082 which uses servlet api 3.0.

I have deployed the war file which uses servlet 2.5 to Apache tomcat 7.0.82.  the app is running is fine and i do not see any immediate issues.

so my question is, is it OK to do this?  I will eventually be rolling out this change to production...

Comment: btw I am using java 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat 7 will run a Servlet 2.5 application just fine.  The biggest thing is to make sure your web.xml specifies the version.  So, for your example, it would look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">

    ...

</web-app>
```

This tells the container (Tomcat in this case) that this web application follows the Servlet 2.5 spec.

Comment: is this for the web.xml withing code e.g. src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml or web.xml within the tomcat\conf\web.xml?

Comment: In your project - `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`

Comment: that one is already defined as followed:<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">