# Tomcat 7: Sonar compliant setHttpOnly(true) for Cookie

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, sonarqube

Below is my Java code for creating `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` from Tomcat 7 API

```
 Cookie c = new Cookie("code", code.trim());
 c.setPath("/public");
 response.addCookie(c);
 response.setStatus(200);
```

Am trying to add `c.setHttpOnly(true);` to make the above code sonar compliant but Eclipse is throwing a compiler error saying `he method setHttpOnly(boolean) is undefined for the type Cookie`, but from the Javadoc of Tomcat 7 API `https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/index.html` I do see that `setHttpOnly()` exists in `Cookie` class, can someone please help me Understand why am I getting the compiler error for adding `c.setHttpOnly(true);`?

Comment: Probably you have conflict versions of Servlet API. Can you check if you don't use version 2.5 which does not have this method?

Comment: Do you use Maven, Gradle or other build tool?

Comment: @Evgeniy I use Maven

Answer (score 3):

The method `setHttpOnly` of the `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` class was added in Servlet 3.0 specification.

Tomcat 7 implements Servlet 3.0 spec but in order to compile your code, you need to add appropriate Maven dependencies.

Make sure you have a dependency on Servlet 3.0 API with scope `provided`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

With this dependency code `cookie.setHttpOnly(true);` will compile.

Appending `HttpOnly` flag to a cookie value manually `response.addHeader("Set-Cookie","name=value; HttpOnly");` most likely would not pass SonarQube check.

The rule https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3330 checks the presence of the `setHttpOnly(true)` method call.

But this SonarQube check can be suppressed by adding `//NOSONAR` comment to the end of line causing the warning:

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("code", code.trim()); //NOSONAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably still use [Servlet API 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980438/can-i-use-apache-tomcat-7-with-servlet-api-2-5)

> web.xml specifies the version
>
> ```
> <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
>           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
>           version="2.5">
> ```

If you use [Servlet 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147113/setting-an-httponly-cookie-with-javax-servlet-2-5), see @dpinya answer for setting HttpOnly:

> For Servlet API 2.5, you can use
>
> ```
> response.addHeader("Set-Cookie","name=value; HttpOnly");
> ```

See also option to set HTTPOnly using [context.xml](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html):

> The session and SSO cookies in Tomcat 7 are being sent with HttpOnly flag by default, to instruct browsers to prevent access to those cookies from JavaScript. This is considered more secure, but it will prevent JavaScripts from accessing the value of the cookie. This **feature can be controlled by useHttpOnly attribute on the Context element**. (This feature is also implemented in latest versions of Tomcat 6.0 but is off by default. It can be enabled by setting useHttpOnly="true" on Context element in a web application or in the global CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml file).